# ASP.NET Core MVC - Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-authentication

I have a general question about using Windows authentication in an ASP.NET Core MVC project.

As far as I could understand is that you can have the authentication based on the Windows user. If I would deploy the website and different clients would connect to the website, would I be able to get all the windows user names that are connecting to the page? And also would they also see different content if I would program the content based on the Windows user that is connecting?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you'll see their login name for that domain.  You can show them different information based on their login.  Remember that this is domain-level authentication.  (So if a user isn't on the domain, they cannot access the site.)  For users to connect from outside of the domain you need a different or additional method to authenticate a user.  (For users oustide of the domain you cannot know what their Windows login name is... unless the browser exposed it.)

Comment: Thank you very much @pcalkins. I only will need domain level authentication since its needed for the users inside the network of my company